# Android - Drawing a circle everytime you press a button

Tags: android

I want that each time i'll be pressing a button the application will draw a circle - that way i have many circles, i cant seem to do it, any suggestions?

My question is:

How do i draw a second circle and then a third circle etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.kellbot.com/2009/06/android-hello-circle/) is what you want. Before asking question try search first.

Comment: Thank you, but its not what i wanted. i wanted to draw a circle everytime i press a button, but the circle that was created before has to be saved on the screen

Comment: You can rework it easy! Save circle in some list holder and repaint them!

Comment: how?.. and thanks for the quick response

Comment: nevermind, found the solution, thank you very much!! :-D